# mongoose schema unique field with additional condition

Tags: mongoose

Help me please how to define Mongoose schema in my case.

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: { type: String, required: true, unique:true },
 deleted: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});
```

I need to have unique "name" only when "deleted" = 0. If "deleted" = 1 my "name" can be not unique.

Comment: you can use pre save and validate there for such conditions or use setters. unique will not help.

Comment: I see, but want to find more pretty solution like use partialFilterExpression. I tried schema.index({name:string, deleted: 1}, {unique: true, partialFilterExpression:{deleted: {$ne: 1}}})